# Grouping entries by days in matrix field

Tags: matrix, sorting, group

So this is proving a lot harder than I thought.

I have a 'tours' section containing tours, which all have several departure dates. Those dates are in a matrix field, entry.data. So there's only one type for that matrix field, and one date picker, so that several dates can be added per entry.

I'm trying to list entries sorted by the day they depart, so it should look like this:

```
07-oct-2015
tour x
tour y

11-oct-2015
tour x
tour z

13-oct-2015
tour x
tour y
tour z
```

Since there isn't a tour departing every day, or on a set schedule, I can't just pull out entries that match a given day..

Any help would be awesome! I saw a similar post that was resolved with the low blocks plugin, but I'm hoping this can be solved natively with grouping and sorting.. :)

Thx!